# MongoDB $graphlookup in Java Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, aggregation

I'm looking for a way to implement graphlookup using Java in a Resful Web API. I'm trying to implement the hierarchy like on the MongoDB (https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/)

```
    { "_id" : 1, "name" : "Dev" }
    { "_id" : 2, "name" : "Eliot", "reportsTo" : "Dev" }
    { "_id" : 3, "name" : "Ron", "reportsTo" : "Eliot" }
    { "_id" : 4, "name" : "Andrew", "reportsTo" : "Eliot" }
    { "_id" : 5, "name" : "Asya", "reportsTo" : "Ron" }
    { "_id" : 6, "name" : "Dan", "reportsTo" : "Andrew" }
```

This is the employee collection, what I want is to be able to create this structure stored in MongoDB

```
 {
   "_id" : 1,
   "name" : "Dev",
   "reportingHierarchy" : [ ]
}
{
   "_id" : 2,
   "name" : "Eliot",
   "reportsTo" : "Dev",
   "reportingHierarchy" : [
      { "_id" : 1, "name" : "Dev" }
   ]
}
{
   "_id" : 3,
   "name" : "Ron",
   "reportsTo" : "Eliot",
   "reportingHierarchy" : [
      { "_id" : 1, "name" : "Dev" },
      { "_id" : 2, "name" : "Eliot", "reportsTo" : "Dev" }
   ]
}
```

I've seen examples like this for aggregation, but nothing on graphlookup

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
        match(Criteria.where("pageId").is("2210")),
        unwind("postIds"),
        group("_id").sum("1").as("sum")
        //project("$sum").and("pageId").previousOperation()
    );
```

Is there a way to get graphlookup into a format like this? Where instead of using match, unwind, group, I can use GraphLookupOperation and then something like get map result.

Answer (score 0):

```
AggregationOperation aggregationOperation = new AggregationOperation() {
        @Override public DBObject toDBObject(AggregationOperationContext aggregationOperationContext) {
            DBObject graphLookup = new BasicDBObject(
                    "from", "individual").append(
                    "startWith", "$reportsTo").append(
                    "connectFromField", "reportsTo").append(
                    "connectToField", "firstName").append(
                    "maxDepth", 2).append(
                    "as", "reportingHierarchy");
            return new BasicDBObject("$graphLookup", graphLookup);
```

This code allows for a workaround since i'm using an older version, I think 1.10.0 spring mongo.  Now I have the issues of the "reportingHierarchy" not looking like I want it to. It's not giving me a name. Just reportsTo and reportingHierarchy that is also including _class which I don't want.